# cc1plus: error: -Werror=literal-suffix: no option -Wliteral-suffix

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5

I'm getting this error while trying to compile Qt 5 for Android (on linux x86_64):

```
cc1plus: error: -Werror=literal-suffix: no option -Wliteral-suffix
```

Anybody ever seen it or know how to resolve it?

Compiler version is "arm-linux-androideabi-g++ (GCC) 4.7"

The whole compilation command that make was running when the error occurred:

```
/home/triumph/Documents/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -Werror -Wno-error=cpp -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-error=strict-overflow -Wno-error=literal-suffix -g -g -gdwarf-2 -marm -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_PRINTER -DQT_NO_PRINTDIALOG -DQT_NO_LIBUDEV -DQT_NO_XCB -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DPCRE_HAVE_CONFIG_H -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../mkspecs/android-g++ -I. -I../../include -I../../include/QtCore -I../../include/QtCore/5.2.0 -I../../include/QtCore/5.2.0/QtCore -Iglobal -I../3rdparty/pcre -I../3rdparty/harfbuzz/src -I../3rdparty/md5 -I../3rdparty/md4 -I../3rdparty/sha3 -I.moc/debug-shared -I/home/triumph/Documents/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include -I/home/triumph/Documents/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -I/home/triumph/Documents/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -o .obj/debug-shared/qabstractanimation.o animation/qabstractanimation.cpp
```

Comment: Have you followed the official building instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error.  I worked around it by deleting "-Wno-error=literal-suffix" from the CXXFLAGS line in Makefile (./qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/).

I also added some default: entries to the switch statements in corelib/global/qlogging.cpp which handled msgType (case QtFatalMsg: etc), since the compiler complained that QtTraceMsg was not being handled.  I treated the default case as a "warning" (treating it as a fatal error could be safer).

p.s. I hit the error using current git (5.2alpha) with the custom ndk-r8e version suggested by  Laszlo's "official building instructions".  I did not get this error using google's latest ndk-r9 with qt git tag v5.1.1 (I don't know if it was the different ndk or the different git revision that made the difference).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a fix made to qt_common.qrf.

The following line was added inside a code block for GCC 4.6 to 4.8, but it references a compiler directive added to GCC 4.7, and therefore produces failing Makefiles when used with GCC 4.6

```
            android: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-error=literal-suffix
```

The solution is to modify the file and add a condition on that line:

```
        contains(ver, "4\\.[78]") { // Doesn't apply to 4.6
            android: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-error=literal-suffix
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when using the 5.2.0-alpha1 tag with the custom android-ndk-r8e.

**Fix by switching to v5.1.1:**

Clean up from your previous build attempt.  Use

```
git clean -f
```

within your qt5 directory, and any submodule directory that is dirty.  After, from your qt5 directory:

```
git checkout v5.1.1
git submodule update --recursive
```

Reconfigure with your QT ./configure command (and any parameters), then make.